# How to subset list elements that lie between two missing values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

With a list containing some missing values such as this:

```
[10, 11, 12,np.nan, 14, np.nan, 16, 17, np.nan, 19, np.nan]
```

How can you subset the values that are positioned between two missing (`nan`) values?

I know how to do it with a `for loop` :

```
# imports
import numpy as np

# input
lst=[10,11,12,np.nan, 14, np.nan, 16, 17, np.nan, 19, np.nan]

# define an empty list and build on that in a For Loop
subset=[]
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    if np.isnan(lst[i-1]) and np.isnan(lst[i+1]):
        subset.extend([elem])

print(subset)

# output
# [14, 19]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this in a less cumbersome way?

Comment: you are already using enumerate so you know the index, its in i, so just use that instaed of elem

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thank you for responding. I was hoping for list comprehension or some vectorized approach to speed things up a bit for larger lists

Comment: Ah ok eternal already gave a list comprehension example

Comment: So for `lst = [1, np.nan]` your desired output is `[1]`?

Comment: And for `lst = [np.nan]` it's ok to crash?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Those are interesting cases! For my real world problem, I would return an empty list in those two cases

Comment: @vestland But that's not what your code is doing. Your code is doing what I said.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I understand, and I'll have to admit that I had not considered those edge cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use list comprehension

```
import numpy as np
lst=[10,11,12,np.nan, 14, np.nan, 16, 17, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
subset = [elem for i, elem in enumerate(lst) if i and i < len(lst)-1 and np.isnan(lst[i-1]) and np.isnan(lst[i+1]) and not np.isnan(elem)]
print(subset)
```

Corrected the mistakes that were pointed out by other contributors. This should work for all the cases now.

Comment: He wanted different approaches to get the desired output

Comment: Yes, that was not tested, I have edited the answer @HeapOverflow

Comment: your output contains the index, it is not the OP desired output + if your second last element is  `np.nan` your code will raise IndexError

Comment: Indeed, didn't think it through @kederrac

Comment: Does it look okay now? @kederrac

Comment: @Eternal Thank you for answering! Any idea on how to do this with a list of mixed types too? `np.isnan` returns a TypeError when the input is a string. I *do not* mind asking this as a new question though...

Comment: Can you use pandas isnull() method? It will work for all types

Answer (score 8):

I'm a NumPy noob, so probably can be done better...

```
>>> a = np.array(lst)
>>> a[1:-1][np.isnan(a[:-2]) & np.isnan(a[2:])]
array([14., 19.])
```

For my examples `[1, np.nan]` and `[np.nan]` in the comments, this produces an empty array as intended.

Or as Georgy commented, do `isnan` only once:

```
>>> a = np.array(lst)
>>> nan = np.isnan(a)
>>> a[1:-1][nan[:-2] & nan[2:]]
array([14., 19.])
```

As kaya3 commented, if there can be three nans in a row, these solutions would include the middle one in the result (like your original does). Here's one that doesn't (for the test I replaced the 14 with a nan):

```
>>> a[1:-1][nan[:-2] & ~nan[1:-1] & nan[2:]]
array([19.])
```

Comment: One small improvement you could do it so take out the calculation of `np.isnan(a)` instead of calculating it twice.

Comment: In case there are sequences of 3 or more NaN values, you can add an `& nan[1:-1]` term.

Comment: @kaya3 Hmm, yeah, should probably check that. Although the OP also didn't do that in their *"I know how to do it with a for loop"* reference solution, so maybe it can't happen or getting the nan is desired. Or it could be yet another thing they overlooked :-). I'll add.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the built-in function `zip`:

```
subset = [e2 for e1, e2, e3 in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:]) if np.isnan(e1) and not np.isnan(e2) and np.isnan(e3)]
print(subset)
```

**output:**

```
[14, 19]
```